# Who put the parentheses in the Gemara, when, and for what reason(s)?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara

From time to time there are parentheses in the gemara (e.g., Taanis 17b).

Who put the parentheses there, when, and for what reason(s)?

Comment: From memory I think that it shows that the printer is erasing the words from the printed edition and adding the words in the square brackets. I am leaving this a comment because I do not have a citation.